# how to select column name with space in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
avgsalary_df = spark.read.csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/BigData2021/Lecture23/datasets/data_scientist_salaries.csv', header = True)
avgsalary_df = df.selectExpr('Job Title' ,'Location', 'salary', 'spark')
avgsalary_df.show()
```

Here is my code but it wont return Job Title column cause of space inside name.what is incorrect?

Comment: By the way , just using `df.select(...)` instead of  `selectExpr` would work fine. However, I'd recommend you to rename that column, avoid having spaces or special characters in column names in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote column names with backticks (`).

```
avgsalary_df = df.select(['`Job Title`', 'Location', 'salary', 'spark'])
```

Comment: try but I have invalid syntax error here..

Comment: Actually there is no need to use backticks with dataframe API only when using SQL. `df.select(*['Job Title', 'Location', 'salary', 'spark'])` would work as well. The OP got that error because they used `selectExpr` not select.